# Choose certain items iterating through a list slice python

Tags: python

I have a list

```
[[0, 1], [1, 0], [0, 2], [1, 1], [2, 0], [0, 3], [1, 2], [2, 1], [3, 0]]
```

I would like to select the indices from the list that meet the following conditions:

1) The sum of the elements is equal to 3

2) The answer to the above sum does not appear in the list

The way I have thought to do this so far : create a new list with the sums of the above list, countersum, and take the indices, idx of those that meet the condition of being equal to 3, and then:

```
  selection=[n for n, x in list[idx[0]:] if sum not in x]
```

So idx[0] should contain the index of the first element in the original list meeting the sum condition,

However this is giving me error and I have no idea why!

```
TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable
```

Any help greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a simple list comprehension:

```
>>> L = [[0, 1], [1, 0], [0, 2], [1, 1], [2, 0], [0, 3], [1, 2], [2, 1], [3, 0]] 
>>> [i for i, j in enumerate(L) if sum(j) == 3 and 3 not in j]
[6, 7]
```

If I understand correctly, what you were trying to do was something like this:

```
[n for n, x in an_integer] # an_integer being an integer because that is what list[idx[0]:] returned
```

And you can't iterate through an integer, hence the error.

Comment: Sorry made a mistake in my post im looking for the indices of the items not the items themselves

Comment: @user1987097 What exactly do you mean by the indices? The index?

Comment: use enumerate while keeping the same logic

Comment: Yes this works perfectly, but I still don't understand why my original attempt won't work. Surely it means that it should start at list[idx[0]] and then iterate onwards?

Comment: @user1987097 No. That's what a for loop does. It goes through each item in a list individually, starting from the beginning :p